# How do I include scripts in a qt application?

Tags: python, pyqt4

I am trying to use four diferents python scripts in a GUI application.

Every script has around 500 code lines. Then I don´t like to include the every full scrip as a function.

This is the skeleton of the application:

```
from FullConversor import *   #this is the .py gui  
import sys    
import datetime
import os
import pandas as pd
import shapefile as shp  
import csv  
import tkinter.filedialog


class FullConversorGUI(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.pushButtonConvert, QtCore.SIGNAL ('clicked()') ,self.conversor)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.pushButtonClose, QtCore.SIGNAL ('clicked()') ,self.close)


    def conversor(self):
        if self.ui.radioButton1.isChecked()== True: 
            pass
        if self.ui.radioButton2.isChecked()== True:  
            pass
        if self.ui.radioButton3.isChecked()== True:  
            pass
        if self.ui.radioButton4.isChecked()== True: 
            pass


if __name__=='__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = FullConversorGUI()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Every radioButton must launch a python script, just  a .py file who runs fine alone.

How do I do that?

Comment: Seriously consider not comparing the return value of a function named `isChecked()` with a Boolean literal.

Answer (score 0):

Call import on your script, and run the main function of it when you need.

Pretend you have a script called `myscript.py`

```
# this is myscript.py

def main():
    # this function will be called from your gui. all your logic should be here.
    print "my script"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # this function is called when you invoke the script from the command line. 
    main()
```

Then in your gui....

```
import myscript

if self.ui.radioButton1.isChecked()== True: 
    myscript.main()
    # continue after the script runs
```

This would result in the following output to stdout:

```
my script
```

Obviously, you wouldn't have just a print statement in myscript.py. You can have it run whatever logic you would like.

Comment: if self.ui.radioButton1.isChecked()== True: 
                myscript.main()

Comment: edited to reflect users specific case. Thanks @kamome

Comment: Well I can´t understand that. I include                                                                                   if __name__ == "__main__":
    main                                                                                                                                at the end of my script but when I import that, the script runs and I can not fix it to a radio button

Comment: @kamome your python script is simply a file. In this case, let's pretend it is called `myscript.py`. If your script is in the same directory as where you are running your gui, you can import it just the same way as you would import a standard library in python (which you have done at the top of your code with `import sys` etc.) Then you are going to call the execution of your script's main method to run it... Please let me know what was unclear in more detail and I'll explain the answer further.

Comment: @kamome a method called `main()` is different from `if __name__ == '__main__'` you can have both in your script. I'll edit my post again to see if you get it.

Comment: @kamome see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do) for a full explanation.

Comment: Well. My script is a 400 code lines  -----example.py  No functions in the script But when I import the example.py at the begining of the pyw script, the example.py runs....but I´d like to run when the radioButton is on

Comment: @kamome so change your script and put everything in one main function... It shouldn't affect the functionality of your code whatsoever.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78579/discussion-between-kamome-and-gil).